# Fazer o MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA colocar a foto em uma imageview

Tags: java, android

Eu precisava abrir o Aplicativo de câmera do Android e tirar a foto. Ao ter a foto tirada, colocar a mesma em uma imageview.

Meu problema é, o cliente quer poder tirar a foto ou então escolher da galeria e eu vi que o `INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA` coloca as opções da galeria, porém ele apenas tira a foto e salva.

É possível fazer com que o `INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA` funcione nos mesmos moldes que o `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fazer com que ele trabalhe igual não, mas tem como saber de onde está vindo a imagem. Lembrando que as permissões devem ser adicionadas:

```
            PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
            REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

    ...
private final int ALTERAR_IMAGEM_INTENT = 1;
    private Uri fotoCameraUri; //vai gravar o caminho da foto
    ...
```

Este método irá adicionar os dois casos, fotos do arquivo ou, foto da camera.

```
private void alterarImagem() {

    File fotoCamera = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/DCIM/", "image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        // Do something for lollipop and above versions
        this.fotoCameraUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", fotoCamera);
    } else {
        // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
        this.fotoCameraUri = Uri.fromFile(fotoCamera);
    }
    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, this.fotoCameraUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem. Irá verificar
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, getString(R.string.cadastro_concluir_acao_utilizando));

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, ALTERAR_IMAGEM_INTENT);
}
```

No activity on result deve verificar de onde veio a imagem e setá-la onde deve ser adicionada, em seu imageview, por exemplo:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            final boolean isCamera = ImageUtils.isCamera(data);

            if (!isCamera && (data.getData() == null || this.getContentResolver().getType(data.getData()) == null
                    || !this.getContentResolver().getType(data.getData()).startsWith("image"))) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.cadastro_string_arquivo_selecionando_nao_e_imagem), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            Uri selectedImageUri;
            if (isCamera) {
                selectedImageUri = this.fotoCameraUri;
            } else {
                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            }

            switch (requestCode) {
                case ALTERAR_IMAGEM_INTENT:

                    bitmapImagemUsuario = //faça o decode da sua imagem

                    if (bitmapImagemUsuario != null) {

                        //faça o que tiver de fazer

                        circleImageViewUsuario.setImageBitmap(bitmapImagemUsuario);
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Pode ser também, somente a falta de permissão, como não vejo seu código. Coloquei um aqui para ajudar mais pessoas também.

Comment: Eu pesquisei mais afundo e realmente não tem como fazer com que ele trabalhe igual. O que eu fiz então foi chamar um AlertDialog com as opções de pegar a imagem da galeria ou de tirar a foto.